# How to use Yii::app()->end() method and how is it different from exit()?

Tags: php, yii, exit

In form validating,I find such codes

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

The manual says that the end() method will terminate the application.
Why to terminate the app? The following codes will not execute?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it's an Ajax request and the code is supposed to return the validation results and then stop code execution. It's the same idea as the Php die function, but allows Yii to run onApplicationEnd cleanup code (if any)

Comment: And what other code would be run when action is finished? Application dies anyway. Or?

Comment: @racky see my answer. It's possible to have behaviors for the app that do other things, such as logging, database cleanup, etc

Comment: @acorncom, if Yii::app()->end() happens between a transaction, is it rolled back automatically during onApplicationEnd ?

Comment: @fortm Don't believe it would be, no

Answer (score 3):

Simply saying, it just terminates the application. What makes it different from php's `exit()` is that it calls the `onEndRequest()` before exiting.

Even though, the documentation says `status` parameter 0 means normal exit while other values mean abnormal exit, it is not practiced as such. The `status` parameter is simply passed to `exit()` function(which output it of course!).

```
Yii::app()->end('saved', true);
```

Even objects can be output as below:

```
Yii::app()->end(json_encode($data), true);
```

*Note: (1)`onEndRequest()` is raised right after the application processes the request. This function can be used to prompt logs and other useful functions.*

[**Yii Documentation of `end()`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#end-detail)

```
/**
* Terminates the application.
* This method replaces PHP's exit() function by calling
* {@link onEndRequest} before exiting.
* @param integer $status exit status (value 0 means normal exit while other values mean abnormal exit).
* @param boolean $exit whether to exit the current request. This parameter has been available since version 1.1.5.
* It defaults to true, meaning the PHP's exit() function will be called at the end of this method.
*/

public function end($status=0,$exit=true)
{
if($this->hasEventHandler('onEndRequest'))
$this->onEndRequest(new CEvent($this));
if($exit)
exit($status);
}
```